# How to plot many datapoints efficiently using javafx or other libraries?

Tags: java, performance, javafx, charts

I have 4 series that I want to plot in one linechart. Each series has around 100.000 datapoints. Now, using javafx linechart, it takes several seconds to build the Chart. Not only that it is slow, it also consumes very much memory.

Does anybody has an idea how to build the desired chart faster. If necessary I would use other java libraries too.

Here is some working code. For numDataPoints = 10000 it runs fine, but for numDataPoints = 70000 it's very slow or even crashes.

Thank you in advance.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Chart extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        prepareStage(stage);

    }

    private void prepareStage(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Chart Demo");
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();



        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        ScatterChart ac = new ScatterChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        ac.setTitle("Segregation");
        ac.setAnimated(false);
        ac.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        ac.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);


        int numDataPoints = 70000;

        for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
            ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> data = FXCollections.<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++)
                data.add(new XYChart.Data<>(i,Math.random() ));
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(data);
            ac.getData().add(series);
        }


        pane.getChildren().add(ac);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("chart.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Chart-FX](https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx) is new on the scene. I ran some samples. It looks promising.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it did not get much better.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked here alread quite often. It is not so much a question of performance but a question of a reasonable tool usage. Do you know how many pixels in a row your monitor device has? If yes, then you can ask yourself the question what you think will remain from your 100.000 data points.

The solution to your problem is to just reduce the amount of data to something reasonable. You can also try to virtualize your display by externally managing the amount and portion of the data that is displayed at a certain point in time, e.g. for scrolling, in a similar way as a TableView would do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx 
was specifically designed having this in mind. Have a look at -- or much better -- try out the examples.

N.B. We use this internally for our accelerator-related data acquisition/display purposes with 10k to 1M data points updated in real-time had a fair Swing-based solution (JDataViewer) but couldn't find anything equivalent compatible with JavaFX ... give it a try... it's free ... and open for contributions and comments.